# iOS - Autolayout not working for main UIView - (screenshots inside)

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, autolayout

I seem to be having problems getting my main UIView in my view controller to stay the same size when going to portrait mode. The screenshots pretty much tell the whole story. This is for iPad and iOS 6.1, XCode 4.6.

[Landscape](http://geeksweep.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/landscape.png)

[Portrait](http://geeksweep.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/portait.png)

And here is a [screenshot of my constraints within XCode](http://geeksweep.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/constraints.png)

It looks like the textviews and the Button from within the view itself stays in the same position and size but the UIView (which is a subview to the view controllers view) does not want to keep the same width and height.

I load this view programmatically via my delegate for a couple of reasons so thats just for a FYI - trying to give as much info as possible.

```
//set starting root view controller to login screen
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    DemoViewController *loginVC = (DemoViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginVC"];
    self.window.rootViewController = loginVC;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeRootVCSplit:) name:@"ChangeRootVCSplitNotification" object:nil];
```

I am learning all there is to know about AutoLayout and was wondering if anyone could help with this? Let me know if you need anymore info. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the view a fixed width constraint and a fixed height constraint (from the menu, Editor --> PIN --> Width and likewise for height), then delete the horizontal and vertical space constraints (leaving the centerX and centerY constraints).

Comment: thanks a bunch! Constraints are sometimes a bear to handle. *Accepted*